# displayed equation immediately after an \item, want it to not leave a blank line

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, enumerate

I have an enumerate environment where each item is just a single displayed equation.  This starts on a new line so the "(a)" ends up on a blank line.  Can I make the displayed equation not skip a line, so that the first line of the displayed equation is aligned with the "(a)"?

I thought `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` would do the trick, but of course it applies to the `\item` as well.

I use enumitem in case that matters; also in Real Life I have adjusted the various spacing parameters so that it looks better that the mwe.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  Each item starts with an ugly blank line.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip} % doesn't work, moves the "(a)" up as well
    \begin{equation*}
      E=mc^2
    \end{equation*}
  \item
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip} % doesn't work, moves the "(b)" up as well
    \begin{align*}
      a^2+b^2 &= c^2
      \\ &= E/m
    \end{align*}
  \item
    In this case we have some text, so it looks right.
    \begin{align*}
      \sin^2x + \cos^2x + e^{\pi i} = 0
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the displayed equations be centered or left-aligned on the respective lines? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Centered.  Think of each displayed equation as being a stack of, say, five equations each one following from the previous.  Normally the five lines would be a block centered on the page; I want the first line of that block to be on the same line as "(a)" instead of on the first line after "(a)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the timing of when LaTeX starts a new paragraph in a list environment. The item tag doesn't get typeset until a new paragraph begins and when there's no text, the paragraph begins (and then ends immediately) when you enter display math mode.

Adding `\mbox{}` after the `\item` command will persuade LaTeX to begin a new paragraph and then your `\vspace` command will work as expected. I would be inclined to wrap up the whole of `\item`, `\mbox` and the `\vspace` into a macro, perhaps `\displaymathitem` to (a) avoid repeating yourself and (2) make it clear to anyone looking at your document what you're trying to do, not least of why is that a change in document class will likely change the required amount to pass to `\vspace`. I'm still not entirely convinced that

> 1. *E* = *mc*²

is the appropriate typographic and textual solution for this, but I don't have a better option, so let's go with it.

Comment: \newcommand\disitem{\item\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}} is not bad.  Interestingly, the align* seems to include a bit more vertical space than the equation*.
FYI my use case involves much larger multiline align* environments, but I tried to keep my MWE simple.  I agree the $E=mc^2$ would look strange as a single-line centred equation the way I'm asking! :)

Comment: I'm marking this one accepted since it is a simple fix that mostly works; but needs tweaking depending on current list spacing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I use inline math with `\hfil`s as a substitute.  One can add `\displaystyle`, if needed.  For the align structures, I substitute an `\alignLongunderstack` (or `\alignShortunderstack`) from the `tabstackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  Each item starts with an ugly blank line.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \hfil$\displaystyle%\begin{equation*}
      E=mc^2
    $\hfil\mbox{}%\end{equation*}
  \item
    \hfil$\alignLongunderstack{%\begin{align*}
      a^2+b^2 =& c^2
      \\ =& E/m
    }$\hfil\mbox{}%\end{align*}
  \item
    In this case we have some text, so it looks right.
    \begin{align*}
      \sin^2x + \cos^2x + e^{\pi i} = 0
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this package; it looks interesting.  I had wondered if it was possible to put multiline align inside inline math.

Comment: @mikenewman `tabstackengine` is an extension of `stackengine`, and does not derive from `amsmath`.  Thus, it's features and limitations are a bit different and not everything carries over from one to the other.  When I wrote it, I was merely trying to emulate features of `amsmath`

Comment: @mikenewman Interestingly, `tabstackengine` builds these tabbed expression by column, whereas `amsmath` builds them by row,